# Why is this code producing an memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

The Leaks Instrument in Xcode shows me an memory leak here. I have commented the affected line which Leaks is complaining about. But I see no error in my memory management...

```
- (void)setupViewController {
    MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    UITabBarItem *tbi = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemDownloads tag:1];
    myVC.tabBarItem = tbi; // LEAK: 128 bytes

    self.myViewController = myVC;

    [myVC release];
    [tbi release];
}
```

I mean... tbi and myVC IS released at the end, and the alloc IS balanced. So what's wrong? I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if MyVc.tabBarItem is already set, whatever it's pointing at may not be deallocated properly, causing a leak.

Comment: The tabbar property of myVC should be a property defined to retain. If you do that, the retention of objects assigned to the property will be maintained automatically.

Comment: well, but tabBarItem is from Apple, not from me ;-) I didn't create any tabBarItem property for my View Controller. Apple did. It would be against the memory management rules if I manually release myVC.tabBarItem just because Apple has forgotten to do so, wouldn't it?

Comment: `tabBarItem` is a property with `retain` semantics. It's very unlikely that there's a leak in the setter.

Answer (score 2):

It just goes to show that at least one of the following statements is true:

1. Instruments is not perfect and sometimes shows leaks where there aren't any (and vice versa).
2. Apple's code is not bug-free.

In fact, both are true.